# Update nearby unpaired bluetooth devices list in listview [Android Studio]

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth

Note: I am completely new to android studio (java) and this is my very first project.

I am trying to scan all (paired and unpaired) bluetooth devices and display a list of these devices on application screen.

I have been successful in getting a list so far but following issues persist:

1) As new unpaired devices are scanned, earlier scanned devices are repeated in the display list as duplicates.

2) If I turn off discover-ability in a device, the list is not updated and keeps showing the turned off (no longer available) device in the list.

**Problem: Bluetooth device list is not updated correctly every time a device becomes available or unavailable.**

I have tried clearing my array list before it is updated. Doesn't seem to work. Also, I understand there are a lot of resources on stackoverflow and other websites that cover similar topics of getting nearby bluetooth device list. I have followed multiple of them and written my code but could not come across anything that could solve this "list update" issue.

I am sharing current code and results. Please suggest edits/additions.

Appreciate your time and help.

***Main Activity Class Code***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;                         //Enable bluetooth request variable
    private static final int REQUEST_DISCOVERABILITY = 1 ;                  //Make bluetooth discoverable request variable

    private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;                                     //Define bluetooth adapter variable

    ArrayList<String> deviceList = new ArrayList<>();                       //Store paired devices list
    ArrayList<String> newDevices = new ArrayList<>();                       //Store available devices list
    ArrayList<String> allDevices = new ArrayList<>();                       //Store all devices for display on screen

    ListView btList;                                                        //Define list UI item



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                    //On activity creation do the following


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);                             //Pre-written -- to set layout as screen UI


        btList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1);                        //Set list variable to UI item in layout


        btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();                   //Initialize adapter


        if(allDevices != null){

            allDevices.clear();                                             //Clear array to display fresh list
        }



        int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},   //Ask for permission to turn on location
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);



    }



    public void btOn(View view){                                           //Bluetooth On event

        if (btAdapter != null) {

            if (!btAdapter.isEnabled()) {                                  //Enable bluetooth if not enables already
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
            else{                                                          //If already enabled display list of paired devices

                pairedList();

            }
        }

    }



    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                pairedList();                                              //If user has enabled bluetooth, show list of paired devices

            }

        }
    }


    public void discoverOn(){                                              //Method for setting bluetooth on discoverable mode
                                                                           //for 5 minutes
        Intent discoverableIntent =
                new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivityForResult(discoverableIntent, REQUEST_DISCOVERABILITY);


    }




    public void scanNewDevices(View view){                                  //Scan for unpaired available bluetooth devices when "scan button" is clicked

        discoverOn();                                                       //Set bluetooth to discoverable

        if (btAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                                                                            //Bluetooth is already in mode discovery mode, we cancel to restart it again
            btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
        btAdapter.startDiscovery();                                         //Start scanning

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);

        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);


    }






    public void pairedList(){                                                //Method gets list of paired devices

        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        if (deviceList != null) {                                            //Clear older list items
            deviceList.clear();
        }

        if(pairedDevices != null) {
            for (BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices) {

                deviceList.add(bt.getName() + '\n' + bt.getAddress());      //Add current items
            }
        }


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Showing Paired Devices",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        allDevices.addAll(deviceList);                                      //Update final display list

        showList();                                                         //Display list on screen

    }


                                                                            //Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND.
    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                                                                            //Discovery has found a device. Get the BluetoothDevice
                                                                            //object and its info from the Intent.
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);



                if(newDevices != null){

                    newDevices.clear();                                     //Clear earlier list

                }


                if (device != null ) {

                    newDevices.add(device.getName() + '\n' + device.getAddress());

                    allDevices.addAll(newDevices);                          //Update new devices in final display list

                    showList();                                             //Display list
                }

            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {                                           //When application is closed,
        super.onDestroy();
                                                                           //Unregister the ACTION_FOUND receiver.
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }



    public void showList(){                                                 //Method to set device list to ListView UI

        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new  ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, allDevices);

        btList.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

***activity_main.xml code: to get understanding of layout***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="96dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:onClick="btOn"
        android:text="@string/btbutton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="305dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="204dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="104dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="104dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="124dp"
        android:onClick="scanNewDevices"
        android:text="@string/button2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

***Current Results***

Duplicate device names and if I turn off any of these devices, they are still displayed in the list.

[image: Duplicate device names and if I turn off any of these devices, they are still displayed in the list]

Comment: Refere this link :https://github.com/tutsplus/Android-BluetoothScannerFinishedProject

Comment: I did come across this link. Could not really understand all of the elements used in this code, for instance DeviceListFragment. Will spend more time on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't clear the existing array list and add all whatever you scan again. There is need of check when you scan next time either add only the items in list or clear both lists then add them again.

Following line needs to be modified.

```
    allDevices.addAll(deviceList);
```

just clear allDevices arraylist before this line will solve your problem.